# Using v.net.flow in QGIS/GRASS GIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, network

When I try to use the [`v.net.flow`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.net.flow.html) tool in QGIS, the output datasets have a value of `0` for every feature in the flow column. Almost every other [`v.net`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.net.html) tool works, such as [`v.net.steiner`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.net.steiner.html) and [`v.net.distance`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.net.distance.html).

How do I get the `v.net.flow` tool to actually output the proper values?**

I have attached the log below.

> Processing algorithm… Algorithm 'v.net.flow' starting… Input
>   parameters: { 'GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER' : 0.0001,
>   'GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER' : 0, 'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None,
>   'GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER' : -1, 'GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO' : '',
>   'GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT' : True, 'GRASS_VECTOR_LCO' : '-r',
>   'arc_backward_column' : None, 'arc_column' : 'Shape_Leng', 'cut' :
>   'F:/Work Stuff/SteinerTree/Steiner/Section 4/cut.shp', 'input' :
>   'F:\Work
>   Stuff\SteinerTree\Steiner\NETWORK3TRY.shp|layername=NETWORK3TRY',
>   'node_column' : None, 'output' : 'F:/Work
>   Stuff/SteinerTree/Steiner/Section 4/flow.shp', 'points' : 'F:/Work
>   Stuff/SteinerTree/Steiner/Section 5/Section5.shp', 'sink_cats' : '',
>   'sink_where' : 'TYPE = 0', 'source_cats' : '', 'source_where' : 'TYPE
>   = 1', 'threshold' : 50 }
>
> g.proj -c proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-76.5 +k=0.9999
>   +x_0=304800 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="F:\Work Stuff\SteinerTree\Steiner\NETWORK3TRY.shp" layer="NETWORK3TRY"
>   output="vector_5c906e50cfc9823" --overwrite -o v.in.ogr
>   min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="F:\Work
>   Stuff\SteinerTree\Steiner\Section 5\Section5.shp"
>   output="vector_5c906e50cfc9824" --overwrite -o g.region
>   n=5027309.435160724 s=5024626.0554929385 e=363198.1515355515
>   w=360651.9582503296 v.net -s input=vector_5c906e50cfc9823
>   points=vector_5c906e50cfc9824 output=net5c906e50d046625
>   operation=connect threshold=50.0 v.db.connect -o
>   map=net5c906e50d046625 table=vector_5c906e50cfc9824 layer=2 v.net.flow
>   input=net5c906e50d046625 source_where="TYPE = 1" sink_where="TYPE = 0"
>   arc_column=Shape_Leng output=outpute1098a53ef12487c97f2a35692f70e87
>   cut=cute1098a53ef12487c97f2a35692f70e87 --overwrite v.out.ogr
>   type="line" input="outpute1098a53ef12487c97f2a35692f70e87"
>   output="F:/Work Stuff/SteinerTree/Steiner/Section 4/flow.shp"
>   format="ESRI_Shapefile" layer=1 -c --overwrite v.out.ogr type="line"
>   input="cute1098a53ef12487c97f2a35692f70e87" output="F:/Work
>   Stuff/SteinerTree/Steiner/Section 4/cut.shp" format="ESRI_Shapefile"
>   layer=1 -c --overwrite Starting GRASS GIS... WARNING: Concurrent
>   mapset locking is not supported on Windows Executing
>   
>   ... C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>chcp 1252 1>NUL C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.proj -c
>   proj4="+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-76.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=304800 +y_0=0
>   +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs" Default region was updated to the new projection, but if you have multiple mapsets
>   `g.region -d` should be run in each to update the region from the
>   default Projection information updated C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>v.in.ogr
>   min_area=0.0001 snap=-1.0 input="F:\Work
>   Stuff\SteinerTree\Steiner\NETWORK3TRY.shp" layer="NETWORK3TRY"
>   output="vector_5c906e50cfc9823" --overwrite -o Over-riding projection
>   check Check if OGR layer  contains polygons...
>   0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100 Creating attribute table for layer ... Column name 
>   renamed to  Importing 8460 features (OGR layer )...
>   0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
>   ----------------------------------------------------- Building topology for vector map ...
>   Registering primitives... C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>v.in.ogr min_area=0.0001
>   snap=-1.0 input="F:\Work Stuff\SteinerTree\Steiner\Section
>   5\Section5.shp" output="vector_5c906e50cfc9824" --overwrite -o
>   Over-riding projection check Check if OGR layer  contains
>   polygons...
>   0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100 Creating attribute table for layer ... Importing 888
>   features (OGR layer )...
>   0..2..4..6..8..10..12..14..16..18..20..22..24..26..28..30..32..34..36..38..40..42..44..46..48..50..52..54..56..58..60..62..64..66..68..70..72..74..76..78..80..82..84..86..88..90..92..94..96..98..100
>   ----------------------------------------------------- Building topology for vector map ...
>   Registering primitives... C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>g.region n=5027309.435160724
>   s=5024626.0554929385 e=363198.1515355515 w=360651.9582503296
>   C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>v.net -s input=vector_5c906e50cfc9823
>   points=vector_5c906e50cfc9824 output=net5c906e50d046625
>   operation=connect threshold=50.0 Copying features...
>   2..5..8..11..14..17..20..23..26..29..32..35..38..41..44..47..50..53..56..59..62..65..68..71..74..77..80..83..86..89..92..95..98..100 Building topology for vector map ...
>   Registering primitives... Copying attributes... Building topology for
>   vector map ... Registering primitives...
>   v.net complete. 0 lines (network arcs) written to output.
>   C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>v.db.connect -o map=net5c906e50d046625
>   table=vector_5c906e50cfc9824 layer=2 The table
>    is now part of vector map
>    and may be deleted or overwritten by GRASS
>   modules Select privileges were granted on the table
>   C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>v.net.flow input=net5c906e50d046625 source_where="TYPE
>   = 1" sink_where="TYPE = 0" arc_column=Shape_Leng output=outpute1098a53ef12487c97f2a35692f70e87
>   cut=cute1098a53ef12487c97f2a35692f70e87 --overwrite Building graph...
>   Registering arcs...
>   1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100 Flattening the graph... Graph was built Writing the output...
>   1..3..5..7..9..11..13..15..17..19..21..23..25..27..29..31..33..35..37..39..41..43..45..47..49..51..53..55..57..59..61..63..65..67..69..71..73..75..77..79..81..83..85..87..89..91..93..95..97..99..100 Building topology for vector map
>   ... Registering
>   primitives... Building topology for vector map
>   ... Registering
>   primitives... C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>v.out.ogr type="line"
>   input="outpute1098a53ef12487c97f2a35692f70e87" output="F:/Work
>   Stuff/SteinerTree/Steiner/Section 4/flow.shp" format="ESRI_Shapefile"
>   layer=1 -c --overwrite **WARNING: 888 points found, but not requested to
>   be exported**. Verify 'type' parameter. Exporting 8460 features...
>   5..11..17..23..29..35..41..47..53..59..65..71..77..83..89..95..100 v.out.ogr complete. 8460 features (Line String type) written to
>    (ESRI_Shapefile format).
>   C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>v.out.ogr type="line"
>   input="cute1098a53ef12487c97f2a35692f70e87" output="F:/Work
>   Stuff/SteinerTree/Steiner/Section 4/cut.shp" format="ESRI_Shapefile"
>   layer=1 -c --overwrite **WARNING: No lines found, but requested to be
>   exported. Will skip this feature type. WARNING: No attribute table
>   found -> using only category numbers as attributes** Exporting 0
>   features... **WARNING: Output layer is empty, no features written**
>   v.out.ogr complete. 0 features (Line String type) written to
>    (ESRI_Shapefile format).
>   C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>exit Execution of
>   
>   finished. Cleaning up default sqlite database ... Cleaning up
>   temporary files... Execution completed in 20.03 seconds Results:
>   {'cut': , 'output':
>   }
>
> Loading resulting layers Algorithm 'v.net.flow' finished